# Passport Session Login Slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

Express loads very slow everytime I do logins...

I made passport work and express validator, etc...
i dont get errors but when i login some users it loads very slow

can i ask some help?

**this is my code... (kind of messy)**

```
// Other modules above... etc
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const postRouter = require('./routes/post');

const app = express();

// Passport config
require('./modules/passport-config')(passport)

// view engine setup
// app engine handlebars

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    genid: genid,
    store: new MariaDBStore({ // Store }),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: { // Cookie },
  })
);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', postRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter)


// res locals messages

// catch 404 and forward to error handler here

// error handler here

module.exports = app;
```

**My login router**

```
router.post('/user/login', (req, res, next) => {
   passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         return next();
      }
      if (!user) {
         req.flash('error_msg', info.message);
         return res.redirect('/login');
      }
      req.logIn(user, err => {
         if (err) {
            return next(err);
         }
         return res.redirect('/users/' + user.Username);
         // return res.send(user);
      });
   })(req, res, next);
});
```

**And my passport-config.js**

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
   passport.use(
      new LocalStrategy(
         { usernameField: 'Username', passwordField: 'Password' },
         (username, password, done) => {
            // Find and Match User
            Users.findOne({ where: { Username: username } })
               .then(user => {
                  if (user == null) {
                     console.log('Username incorrect')
                     return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Username incorrect.',
                     });
                  }
                  // Find and Match Password
                  bcrypt.compare(password, user.Password, (err, isMatch) => {
                     if (err) throw err;
                     console.log(isMatch)

                     if (isMatch) {
                        console.log('Password correct. Authentication correct')
                        return done(null, user);
                     } else {
                        console.log('Password incorrect')
                        return done(null, false, {
                           message: 'Password incorrect',
                        });
                     }
                  });
               })
               .catch(err => console.log(err));
         }
      )
   );

   passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
      done(null, user.id)
   });

   passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
      Users.findByPk(id).then(user => done(null, user)).catch(err => console.log(err))
   });
}
```

**the user router is here**

```
router.get('/:user', (req, res) => {
  res.render('user', { layout: 'layout-user' }, { user: req.user });
});
```

but whenever it gets `return res.redirect('/users/' + user.Username)`  to that... it loads very slow...

**Is there something wrong with my code??? Just learned how to use express, etc**

Comment: what your mean the page loads very slow? tell me the response time

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi the page wont load anymore... it wont display anything...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed what's wrong now...

It's in my node sass middleware
I had a sass middleware

on the link `app.use('/users', usersRouter)` instead of pointing to *css/style.css* which is in the root of my public folder... It points to *users/css/style.css*

I fixed it now

Thnxx